# Distinct in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, distinct

I am executing the following query,

```
Select distinct
  a.cr_id,
  Case 
    When ca.ca_vote = 'Approve' and ca.ca_title='MANAGER' Then ca.ca_email
    When ca.ca_vote = 'Reject' Then ''
    When ca.ca_vote = 'Pending' Then ''
    When ca.ca_vote = 'IN PROCESS' Then ''
  End as ca_email
from
  credit a
  inner join credit_approvals ca on ca.c_id=a.cr_id
where 
  a.cr_cs_date between Convert(varchar(20),'11/16/2011',101) and dateadd(day,1,convert  (varchar(20),'11/16/2011',101))
order by
  a.cr_id
```

Despite `distinct` for `cr_id`, it is still displaying the duplicate values. Please let me know how to handle this, so that I could able to display only distinct records.

Comment: Distinct applies to all the columns in your row.  So if 2 cr_ids have the same value  but different ca_email values, you will get one row for each.

Comment: Which ca_email do you want to display in the event of more than one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Distinct` is applied to all columns, not the one which is immediately after `Distinct`.

If you have several different `ca_email` for a `cr_id`, you will see them all.

If you don't want that, you have to come up with a rule to decide what record among the duplicates must stay.