# Why distinct is not working at this sql query ? - complex query

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-server-2008-r2, distinct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Distinct in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173137/distinct-in-sql-server)

I want to select disctinct PokemonId variables but it is not working

here the query

```
select distinct top 36 
    tblFoundPokemonsOnRoutes.pokemonId,MonsterTotalStats,
    MAX(maxLevel) as maxLevel,
    Case Class WHEN 'Ancient' Then '9' 
      WHEN 'Legendary' Then '8' 
      WHEN 'Zenith' Then '7' 
      WHEN 'Emissary' Then '6' 
      WHEN 'Starter' Then '5' 
      WHEN 'Superior' Then '4' 
      WHEN 'Regular' Then '3' 
      ELSE Class 
    END as Result 
from 
    tblFoundPokemonsOnRoutes 
left join 
    tblPokedex on tblFoundPokemonsOnRoutes.pokemonId = tblPokedex.PokemonId 
where 
    tblFoundPokemonsOnRoutes.routeId in 
          (select routeId from tblRoutes where ZoneNumber = 1) 
group by 
    maxLevel, tblFoundPokemonsOnRoutes.pokemonId, MonsterTotalStats, Class 
order by 
    Result desc, MonsterTotalStats desc
```

Here the returned results

[image]

thanks a lot for the answers

Comment: I don't see any duplicated rows ... which ones do you think are duplicate and should be eliminated by `DISTINCT`??  `DISTINCT` only works on **ALL** columns in your `SELECT` - only if all values are identical will a row be excluded.

Comment: because they do not repeat across all columns e.g. the `maxlevel` varies

Comment: @marc_s oh i see. aren't there anyway i can make it distinct for PokemonIds ?

Comment: what would by your expected output?

Comment: So - given `PokemonId = 14` - which of the three rows do you expect to get? You need to be clear on that....

Comment: @marc_s yes PokemonId need to be unique. And i need to select maximum level row one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not include `MaxLevel` in your `GroupBy` clause. Do it this way :

```
select distinct top 36 
    tblFoundPokemonsOnRoutes.pokemonId,MonsterTotalStats,
    MAX(maxLevel) as maxLevel,
    Case Class WHEN 'Ancient' Then '9' 
      WHEN 'Legendary' Then '8' 
      WHEN 'Zenith' Then '7' 
      WHEN 'Emissary' Then '6' 
      WHEN 'Starter' Then '5' 
      WHEN 'Superior' Then '4' 
      WHEN 'Regular' Then '3' 
      ELSE Class 
    END as Result 
from 
    tblFoundPokemonsOnRoutes 
left join 
    tblPokedex on tblFoundPokemonsOnRoutes.pokemonId = tblPokedex.PokemonId 
where 
    tblFoundPokemonsOnRoutes.routeId in 
          (select routeId from tblRoutes where ZoneNumber = 1) 
group by 
     tblFoundPokemonsOnRoutes.pokemonId, MonsterTotalStats, Class 
order by 
    Result desc, MonsterTotalStats desc
```

Comment: working pretty well. can you explain the logic behind ?

Comment: You probably know , distinct removes the rows which are exactly the same , but as you included MaxLevel in your Group by clause , it made rows to be different so the Distinct didn't work.