# DISTINCT Is not working in inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.fbid, u.name,r.points
        FROM users u, players_records r
            WHERE u.fbid = r.user_id
ORDER BY r.points DESC LIMIT 5
```

I want to get the top players but only different 5 players, this query is not working it shows duplicated users ids
any help ?

Result for the above query

```
1112222 Name 1 9310
3334444 Name 2 8380
3334444 Name 2 7010
5555666 Name 3 6080
1112222 Name 1 4890
```

so the ids are duplicated

Comment: Edit your question and include sample data and desired results.  Also, explain what "not working" really means.  And, as a general rule, learn to use proper explicit `join` syntax.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Distinct in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173137/distinct-in-sql-server)

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: You are including r.points in your SELECT, therefore you will get multiple rows per user where that particular user's points differ.

Comment: Your error in reasoning: DISTINCT works on *all* selected columns, not on the one column following the DISTINCT keyword.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` isn't some piece of voodoo, how does it know you only want the first 2 columns distinct? How did you imagine it would know that? `SELECT DISTINCT` works across the entire row - every last part of every row - to determine if that row is different from all other rows. Hence it cannot do what you imagined it might do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want the maximum point per user. So you could do it something like this:

```
SELECT
    users.fbid, 
    users.name,
    maxRecords.points
FROM
    users
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            MAX(players_records.points) AS points,
            players_records.user_id
        FROM
            players_records
        GROUP BY
            players_records.user_id
    ) AS maxRecords
    ON maxRecords.user_id=users.fbid
ORDER BY 
    maxRecords.points DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

If I understand you data. Then the output will be like this:

```
1112222 Name 1 9310
3334444 Name 2 8380
5555666 Name 3 6080
```

Comment: This is much more complicated than necessary.  Drumbeg's answer does the same thing and is much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You could just select max score and group by user.

```
SELECT u.fbid, u.name, MAX(r.points) max_points
FROM users u, player_records r
WHERE u.fbid = r.user_id
GROUP BY u.fbid, u.name
ORDER BY max_points DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Have removed. Good spot.

Answer (score 1):

If you need TOP 5 players by points:

```
SELECT TOP 5 u.fbid, u.name, max(r.points) AS points
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN players_records r ON u.fbid = r.user_id
GROUP BY u.fbid, u.name
ORDER BY points DESC
```

If you need TOP 5 players by SUM points:

```
SELECT TOP 5 u.fbid, u.name, SUM(r.points) AS points
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN players_records r ON u.fbid = r.user_id
GROUP BY u.fbid, u.name
ORDER BY points DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might resemble what you want.

```
select fbid, u.name, sum(r.points) totalpoints
from users u join players_records r on u.fbid = r.user_id
group by fbid, u.name
order by totalpoints desc
limit 5
```

Comment: Limit will work on MySQL, not SQL Server. Let's hope OP meant MySQL.

Comment: I dont want to sub the points, I just want to show the top 5 and players are not duplicated

Comment: @Dan Bracuk: Peril obviously means "don't want to *sum* the points", i.e. just use the maximum points. Which simply means replace `sum` with `max` in your query. Just as you said actually: "might resemble what you want".